# ARKit 4 - Get real world textures on .obj file (or any other 3D format - .ply / .usdz)

Tags: swift, 3d, arkit, lidar

I am trying to get textures in the 3D model I am creating from the ARKit scene reconstruction mesh.
I am able to export the the mesh in a .obj file. The framework is also creating the .mtl file. However, there is no color in the mesh.
I want to add real world textures to the mesh, possible from the arFrame.capturedImage to make the model look more real. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

"[The Visualizing and Interacting with a Reconstructed Scene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene) sample project is showing the beautiful mesh with colors by leveraging the arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding) call.
This shows the mesh, with colors, using a debug method, which is not publicly accessible, nor representative of any particular color scheme relevant for export."
Information by @brandonK212 answer from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654431).